# Error: "You're already syncing this account" in OneDrive for Business for Mac

Tags: sync, onedrive, office365

When trying to add a work/school account to my OneDrive client I get "You're already syncing this account. Open your OneDrive - [company name] folder or sign in with a different account." The available options are "Open my [two spaces] folder", "Quit OneDrive", "Try again".
After uninstalling the client and installing it again, the problem persists.

Does anyone know how to wipe the OneDrive settings in macOS? I tried looking into "Application Support", to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I found two files, called **UBF8T346G9.OneDriveSyncClientSuite.plist** and **UBF8T346G9.OfficeOneDriveSyncIntegration.plist** in **/Users/[username]/Library/Group Containers/**, that contain all the information about the syncing. The first one (*ClientSuite*) has all the information about the accounts you are logged into, the second one (*Integration*) has all the information about the folders in SharePoint you have ever connected to.
- Instead of going nuclear and deleting both files, I opened both plists with Xcode and deleted the infringing accounts from *ClientSuite* and all the unnecessary *SharePoint* syncs from Integration. But I believe it would be safe to just delete both files.

Answer (score 0):

Building on [@catalandres's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1281299/163123), my issue was that `UBF8T346G9.OneDriveSyncClientSuite.plist` file had a stale + duplicate account entry in it.

For example, I have one personal and business account I sync, but my accounts in the file were:

1. `AccountInfo_Business1`
2. `AccountInfo_Business2`
3. `AccountInfo_Personal`

The entries for `AccountInfo_Personal` and `AccountInfo_Business2` appeared correct, but the entry for `AccountInfo_Business1` appeared to be stale.

To resolve the problem, I:

1. Deleted the `AccountInfo_Business1` key-value pair
2. Renamed `AccountInfo_Business2` to `AccountInfo_Business1`
3. Saved my edits to `UBF8T346G9.OneDriveSyncClientSuite.plist`
4. Launched OneDrive

After following the above steps, both accounts synced as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue using my iMac and this solved it:

1. Quit OneDrive. (Select the cloud icon in the top tray, then select Settings > Quit OneDrive.)
2. Find OneDrive in your Applications folder.
3. Right-click OneDrive and select Show Package Contents.
4. Browse to the Contents > Resources folder.
5. Double-click ResetOneDriveApp.command (or ResetOneDriveAppStandalone.command, if you're using the standalone app).
6. Start OneDrive and finish the setup process.